# filter groups in a DataFrameGroupBy that have a value false

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that I have grouped by `student`

```py
grouped_dummy_df = dummy_df.groupby('student')
grouped_dummy_df['pass_fail'].value_counts()
```

Outputting:

```
student           pass_fail
student1          True          8
                  False         2
student2          True          7
                  False         2
student3          True         16
                  False         2
student4          True          9
student5          True          9
student6          True          9
student7          True          9
student8          True          9
```

I would like to remove groups, `students`, that do not have `False` from my data frame. So `student4` through `student8` would be removed.

Comment: what happens if you do `x = grouped_dummy_df['pass_fail'].value_counts()` and then `x[x.pass_fail = False]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We using `transform` with `all` filter the df first

```
dummy_df[~grouped_dummy_df.pass_fail.transform('all')].groupby('student')['pass_fail'].value_counts()
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the logic behind the first indexing?

Comment: @Yuca first one , is to remove all True students